# C++/QT - QFileDialog::getOpenFileName filter *.xml disables files with japanese characters in their name

Tags: c++, qt, macos, filter, qfiledialog

I'm trying to use a QFileDialog::getOpenFileName with an xml filter defined tr("XML Files (*.xml)") to ask the user to select an XML file.

However, in case there's a file in the directory that has japanese characters in its name ( e.g: ラドクリフ.xml ), the file is shown to be disabled, so the user can't select it. Other files, such as a.xml, b.xml are shown to be select-able.

Why is this happening ? Is there a way to fix this ?

Thanks!

Comment: That's a typo, right ? It should be `tr("XML files (*.xml)")`

Comment: I think you're going to need to post the whole of your file dialog code for us to get further with your problem

Answer (score 1):

The file is not "ラドクリフ.xml" it is "ラドクリフ.xml" note the xml at the end of the filename is not ASCII; they are full width Roman letters i.e. [UniCode codepoints 0xFF00-0xFFEF](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml).

The fix is for your users to switch back to ASCII input when typing the .xml at the end, or if your software is localised for Japanese add full width "*.xml" to your list of filters.

Comment: Clever!! Thanks a lot, but I will confirm this as the answer shortly after trying it :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not this - I changed the encoding of my terminal to ASCII and re-checked. The filename part in katakana was  displayed weirdly( as expected in ASCII ), but the .xml remained .xml , so this must mean that the .xml is not full width .xml.

Comment: Also, to confirm your answer, i'd passed ("\*.\*", "*" ) as filters, and also not passed any filter ( in which case, all the files should be shown according to QFileDialog ), but to no avail. These files were STILL not selectable ! Looks like a Qt Bug on mac to me.

Comment: I would 1. double check that these are xml files and not directories with an extension. 2. get a QDir object on the directory and go through all the strings in the entryList()

Comment: I am using a filter in one of my projects on MacOS X and I already made a test case of a Japanese name with ASCII extension and I'm using a QFileDialog with a filter so I can confirm that if it's a bug it doesn't affect my project.

Comment: Also, if Finder is set to hide extensions, your file could really be ラドクリフ.xml.txt and the filter would disable it.

Comment: nice hypotheses all, but the directory one is incorrect because other directories within the folder are being shown as selectable/browsable, while these are just disabled.

Also, finder is not set to hide the extensions because I had made some a.xml like dummy files and it showed a.xml for them ( their extension ), and showed them as disabled, while i could simultaneously see these japanese name .xml files disabled :(

Comment: Just to add, I was able to make this work by using Cocoa native calls to make a file dialog, and that showed these files as enabled. This makes me even more suspicious that the bug is in QFileDialog code that basically checks if a file is to be shown or not ..

My Mac OS X is 10.6.7 - I hope yours is not - Thanks a lot for the effort - please let me know of any other reasons why I could be wrong about QT.